# phpファイルとapacheがうまく連携出来てません。

Tags: php, apache

phpは"It works!"となるのですが、特定のファイルにアクセスすようとすると

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/Library/WebServer/Documents/dbtest3.php' (include_path='.:') in Unknown on line 0
```

となってしまいます。mamp関連のphpファイル等も消したはずなのですが。
何か解決方法が思いつく方は教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/Library/WebServer/Documents/dbtest3.php' (include_path='.:') in Unknown on line 0

`Permission denied` と表示されてるので .php ファイルのアクセス権限が無いため ファイルを読み込めないのだと思います。

ファイルのパーミッションとオーナー、グループを確認して 設定しなおしてみてください。
よく分からなければ `chmod 644 /Library/WebServer/Documents/dbtest3.php` を実行してみてなにか変化がないか確認してみてください。